# Adobe Media Server Docker

Tags: docker, adobe-media-server

I need to put Adobe Media Server in a docker container. This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6

WORKDIR /

ADD . /

RUN tar -xzf AdobeMediaServer5_x64.tar.gz
RUN rm -Rf ./AMS_5_0_15_r5004/License.txt
RUN sed -i -e 's:read cont < /dev/tty:#read cont < /dev/tty:g' ./AMS_5_0_15_r5004/installAMS
RUN ./AMS_5_0_15_r5004/installAMS < ./installAMS.input

EXPOSE 1935
```

installAMS.input

```
\n
\n
/opt/adobe/ams
homestead
homestead
homestead
ams
y
ams
n
1935,80
1111
y
y
y
```

But on server start, this errors is throw:

```
Server:ams command:start
error: "Read-only file system" setting key "kernel.sem"
```

And server doesn't work.

Comment: can you add the run command?

Comment: @gCoh sudo docker build -t aib-server .

Comment: so where is the entrypoint where you run it?

Comment: The server is started after install...

Answer (score 0):

"Read-only file system" is probably unrelated to any issue with your docker file . When I get that error, I can often resolve with `docker system prune`

You can see an example of a working Dockerfile for Adobe Media Server here: https://github.com/veriskope/docker-adobe-media-server